# What does it mean to call someone a wipe?

Tags: offensive-language

By the swear words I know it is some insult, I posted this as an answer because the question was stupid. but I am not sure what it exactly means. I heard it in [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyd1-nb4fBA) at about 0:21 for reference. This is the exact quote: "But Chief, Art class is easy you fucking wipe!" What does this mean beyond it being an insult?

Comment: Beyond being an insult, in your provided quote, it means art class is easy! :-)

Comment: probably short for *asswipe* or something like that.

Comment: What video? Link please.

Comment: @Mitch Ok I provided an link tank you for the clarification

Comment: MODERATOR WARNING: Do not place offensive language in the title of your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is someone calling the person  an "arse-wipe", a piece of toilet paper or a cloth used to wipe ones bottom!  There are probably may connotations, but the cleanest [pardon the expression], is probably suggesting the person is unpleasant and menial.